# dish washer not spinning

Tags: dishwasher

The dishwasher fills with water, but it doesn’t seem to be spinning, only producing heat. Upon opening you can see water on the bottom, it drains the water fine if I cancel the cycle. I’ve tried resetting using the 1-2-3 button cycle on front which did not work. No matter if the cycle is on tough normal light or express it doesn’t seem to work. I can hear intermittent clicking. All of the LEDS work. Any help would greatly be appreciated. The model is: kitchen aid KDFE104DSS4

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: From your question, it is not working well.  Don't give enough information for us to give a good answer, but a google search of model and not spinning has many hits.  Would try from of those sites/posts and then can come back if you need more help.

Comment: first suggestion is to manually spin the spray arms, if you can't the dishwasher won't be able to.  sometimes rubber bands, hair, string etc can jamb the spin mechanism.  you could also just have a piece of tupperware that is jammed preventing the spinning.

Comment: Just a SWAG; After following Fresh Codemonger's instructions and it is OK,  Put a glass or cup in the upper and lower racks open end up. At the end of the wash but before dry they should be full. You should also hear if the arm is spinning, you can open the door quickly and see if there is a water trail. For a real answer you need to give us the information asked for by crisp659.